# As an intern, what can I do to eventually convert to a full-time employee?

Tags: internship, graduate

I will start my 12-week internship. I understand that I will face some challenges in the workplace. What can I do to eventually convert to a full-time employee? How should I demonstrate myself in the workplace?

It is a corporate environment, and I will be working for the finance team. I barely have any working experience, only internship.

Comment: Listen, learn, volunteer, try to find a mentor in a more tenured person with a similar personality, and show up on time. The rest will follow if there’s an available full time position

Comment: Ask the employer with whom you're interning.  They may tell you "why don't you complete your 12 week internship and we'll see how it goes?  If you knock our socks off, we might find a place for you."

Comment: I would talk to your manager on how your performance will be measured and what success looks like to them.

Comment: Just saying: I have worked with one guy who started as an intern, and when he was ready to get a full time job, the company _asked_ him to apply for a job. Which he got without even a job interview; they considered the internship as a 12 week interview. Many companies will mark your file as "hire", "don't hire", or "interview". Same is also true if you do a temp job.

Comment: The only people who can tell you the answer are at the employer with whom you are interning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of factors that determine if an intern will be hired as a full-time employee, only some of which are under your control.

It's possible that the company does not hire interns, or hires only a small percentage. It could be that there are different standards and requirements for a full-time employee than there are for interns.

This is all to say: don't worry about what you cannot control. Your best chance to be hired as an full-time employee is to act like one. Don't sell yourself short because you're "only an intern."

Do your best work over the 12 weeks. Ask questions if you're stuck or unsure what to do. Be proactive. If you don't have work, find out what you can do to help people. Look for systems, processes, or tasks you can improve, increase efficiency, or eliminate waste. Make sure you get permission before making changes.

Take notes. Pay attention to everything that's going on around you, even if it doesn't seem relevant at the time. Be someone who people can count on.

Answer (score 0):

> what can I do to eventually convert to a full-time employee?

1. Ask your boss (your closest manager). Find out how your success is measured.
2. Excel at what your boss is looking for.
3. Profit.

Answer (score 0):

Be pleasant to work with.  Get your work done to your best of your ability.  Ask questions when needed, but be mindful of the workload of the full time workers (if they're busy, wait or ask someone else).  Under promise and over deliver-  don't talk up what you're going to do, do it then talk up what you've done.